# Cities skylines save game physically in folder but not appearing in content manager or load game menu

Tags: cities-skylines

I recently saved my city and closed the game, the next day when i went to load it it didn't appear. after searching on google people said to check whether the file is in appdata/user... and it is there but when i check in content manager it isn't.

Comment: Me too. Worse - it's my kiddo's save game.